# For each unique entry in a list, add a range of dates in R?

Tags: r

So I have a list of unique values such as:

```
Ben
April
Joe
```

I want to create a data frame where for each entry in this list there is a date from a date range (1/1/2000 - 1/2/2000) entered

```
Ben    1/1/2000
Ben    1/2/2000
April  1/1/2000
April  1/2/2000
Joe    1/1/2000
Joe    1/2/2000
```

I have tried doing this will lubridate and dplyr but I haven't had any luck

Comment: I don't see how your unique values relate to the desired output. Could you show your lubridate and dplyr approaches?

Comment: for each unique value and unique date in the range there is a final entry in the data.frame.

Comment: so if there are 20 unique values, and 10 days in the date range there would be 200 rows in the final table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
vals <- c("Ben", "April", "Joe")
dateRange <- seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-03"), "1 day")
expand.grid(vals, dateRange)
# Var1       Var2
# 1   Ben 2000-01-01
# 2 April 2000-01-01
# 3   Joe 2000-01-01
# 4   Ben 2000-01-02
# 5 April 2000-01-02
# 6   Joe 2000-01-02
# 7   Ben 2000-01-03
# 8 April 2000-01-03
# 9   Joe 2000-01-03
```

Comment: This approach is great. Much quicker than a for loop I came up with